# Java Process send SIGINT

Tags: java, sigint

I have following Java Process (Windows):

```
Process cmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping google.com -n 10000");
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(cmd.getOutputStream()));
```

Now I want to cancel this process with Ctrl+C (NOT destroy).
I tried this:

```
char ctrl = (char) 3;
writer.write(ctrl);
writer.flush();
```

But the process does not end.
Also  `writer.write("/c")` does not work.

How can i finish a process with SIGINT or rather Ctrl+C?

Answer (score 0):

Using `cmd.destroy();` should ensure that the sub-process ends, then `cmd.waitFor()` should return non-zero exit code.

However also note that as you don't consume the output stream of the sub-process, the ping may halt if the `cmd.getInputStream()` fills with output before you read it.

Comment: i want to end it with Ctrl+C or SIGINT. If I destroy the process, this is another behavior, or? So I want to write it inot the output stream.

Comment: Ctrl-C mapping to SIGINT is a feature of shell, sending character 3 to stdin isn't going to stop it. You should use `destroy()` when you decide to stop the process or can run your own command `kill -s SIGINT <yourpid>`